# Sobrescribir un archivo en java

Tags: java, archivo, filewriter

Me gustaria escribir en un archivo en java en el que ya hay información, cuando utilizo

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

El contenido se me escribe en la misma linea cuando me gustaría que empezase en la siguiente, es decir que añada un intro.
Si el archivo ya tiene Hola, quiero que si escribo Hola otra vez aparezca

> hola
>
> hola

y no

> holahola

Este es todo mi método:

```
public class WriteFile {

    public static void Write() {

        try {

            String path = "C:\\Users\\bea_d\\eclipse-workspace\\politics.txt";
            File file = new File(path);
            String message = "HOLA que tal";

            if(!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true); 
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(message);
            bw.close();


        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque te falta agregar un enter (\r\n).  Podrías hacer algo así:

```
public class WriteFile {

    public static void Write() {

        try {

            String path = "C:\\Users\\bea_d\\eclipse-workspace\\politics.txt";
            File file = new File(path);
            String message = "HOLA que tal";

            if(!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();
            else
                message = "\r\n" + message;

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true); 
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(message);
            bw.close();


        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar otra clase para escribir en el archivo `PrintWriter`, el código te quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```java
public static void Write() {

    try {

        String path = "C:\\Users\\bea_d\\eclipse-workspace\\politics.txt";
        File file = new File(path);
        String message = "HOLA que tal";

        if(!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true); 
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(bw);

        pw.println(message);

        pw.close();
        bw.close();
        fw.close();


    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```